# Join lists and individual floats to single string in Python

Tags: python

Given the following list:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.2, 1.4], [2.0, 2.2], 5.0]
```

How to I get:

```
s = '1.0 1.2 1.4 2.0 2.2 5.0
```

I can't seem to be able to build something out of join(), map() or list comprehensions that doesn't fail due to the non-iterable last member.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: You can also check this answer, which compares several methods of flattening a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is bit hackish but does the JOB with minimum effort

```
>>> a = [[1.0, 1.2, 1.4], [2.0, 2.2], 5.0]
>>> str(a)
'[[1.0, 1.2, 1.4], [2.0, 2.2], 5.0]'
>>> str(a).translate(None,'[],')
'1.0 1.2 1.4 2.0 2.2 5.0'
```

Comment: Yeah, I put a similar approach in a comment, but +1 for having the guts to actually give it as an answer. :^)  One advantage is that it'll handle arbitrary levels of list nesting automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [[1.0, 1.2, 1.4], [2.0, 2.2], 5.0]
>>> ' '.join(str(s) for x in a for s in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]))
'1.0 1.2 1.4 2.0 2.2 5.0'
```

This is equivalent in behavior to the following for loop:

```
tmp = []
for x in a:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for s in x:
            tmp.append(s)
    else:
        tmp.append(x)
result = ' '.join(tmp)
```

Note that this assumes only one level of nesting, as in your example.  If you need this to work with any arbitrary iterable instead of only lists you can use [`collections.Iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), as long as your values are not strings (otherwise it will iterate over the characters in the string).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.2, 1.4], [2.0, 2.2], 5.0]

def try_iter(item):
    try:
        return iter(item)
    except:
        return (item,)

from itertools import chain

print ' '.join(str(s) for s in chain.from_iterable(map(try_iter, a)))
```